# Deserialize JSON in apex. JSON has object array

Tags: apex, json

I have a JSON which I'm trying to deserialize into the apex class.

JSON structure :

```
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "entry": [
    {
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "test"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": "200"
      }
    },
    [
      {
        "resource": {
          "resourceType": "test"
        },
        "response": {
          "status": "200"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

how to deserialize this JSON structure using the apex wrapper class?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Try creating a `.json` file (e.g. in VSCode) with this content and you'll see it gets marked with various errors. Once you have valid JSON you may find it easier to answer your own question.

Comment: Added the valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JSON2Apex](https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/json2apex) tool to generate the Apex class from the JSON string.

For example, you can use the following code to create an Apex class called Bundle:

```
public class Bundle {
        public String resourceType;
        public List<Entry> entry;

        public class Entry {
                public Resource resource;
                public Response response;
        }

        public class Resource {
                public String resourceType;
        }

        public class Response {
                public String status;
        }
}
```

Use the `JSON.deserialize` method to deserialize the **JSON** string into an **Apex** object of the **Bundle** class. You can pass the **JSON** string and the **Bundle** class as the parameters of the method.

For example, you can use the following code to deserialize the **JSON** string into a **Bundle** object:

```
String jsonString = '{ "resourceType": "Bundle", "entry": [ { "resource": { "resourceType": "test" }, "response": { "status": "200" } }, [ { "resource": { "resourceType": "test" }, "response": { "status": "200" } } ] ] }';
Bundle bundle = (Bundle) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, Bundle.class);
```

Access the properties and methods of the **Bundle** object as needed. You can use **dot notation** or **square brackets** to access the properties of the object or the elements of the list.

For example, you can use the following code to access the resource type and the status of the first entry in the bundle:

```
String resourceType = bundle.entry[0].resource.resourceType;
String status = bundle.entry[0].response.status;
```

I hope this helps you to deserialize the JSON structure using the Apex wrapper.